How to get read and write bytes/s of a process
I know that you can monitor read_bytes and write_bytes of a process with psutil.io_counters() in Python, but it returns all read/written bytes of a process during its duration. Is there a way to do the same, but so it return values per second, kinda like pidstat -dl?

use cpu_times() do a sampling of both cpu_times()  and io_counters() and do the maths ?

Research enough. The psutil does not provide API for getting the rate. Why not measure two times and calculate the rate? But don't use the cpu_times() as in the above comment. Use time.monotonic() instead.

@M1hv771 whats the difference between the two times ?

I see : Warning CPU times are always supposed to increase over time, or at least remain the same, and that’s because time cannot go backwards. Surprisingly sometimes this might not be the case (at least on Windows and Linux), see #1210.

@pippo1980 You had to write @relent95 to notify me. It's because cpu_times() does not return real time timestamps. See this question.
